# Django custom field has no attribute 'set_attributes_from_name'

Tags: django

I have a custom field to convert the input date to a timedelta in years, rounded up:

```
class CustomField(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()

    def days_to_years(self, date: timedelta):
        return math.ceil(date.days / 365)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        delta = datetime.today() - self.start_date
        self.start_date = math.ceil(delta.days / 365)
        super(CustomField, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Which I use in models like:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Component(ComponentBase):
    years = ArrayField(
            CustomField()
    )
```

When I try to make migrations, the error `AttributeError: 'CustomField' object has no attribute 'set_attributes_from_name` is raised, which I can't seem to debug because I'm still quite fresh to Django. Any suggestions would be very welcoming :).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your own custom field it should be a subclass of models.Field, not models.Model.

Comment: Didn't work. It messed up the migrations and I had to revert..